# How to use more than 2 SearchTerms in JavaMail?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I have currently the problem that I want to use more than 2 SearchTerms. How is this possible?
I have the following currently - but I can use only two terms in the AndTerm?

```
SearchTerm subjectSearchTerm = new SubjectTerm(searchValue);
SearchTerm bodyTerm = new BodyTerm(searchValue);
SearchTerm fromTerm = new FromStringTerm(searchValue);
SearchTerm searchTerm = new AndTerm(subjectSearchTerm, bodyTerm);
```

How can I change this?

Comment: Have you tried nesting them (eg `new AndTerm(fromTerm, new AndTerm(subjectSearchTerm, bodyTerm))`)?

Comment: Great. that´s working. many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have now is basically `(subjectSearchTerm  AND bodyTerm)`. If you want to add another term, you need to create the equivalent of `(fromTerm AND (subjectSearchTerm  AND bodyTerm))`:

```
new AndTerm(fromTerm, new AndTerm(subjectSearchTerm, bodyTerm))
```

Answer (score 1):

[AndTerm takes an array of search terms](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/docs/api/javax/mail/search/AndTerm.html#AndTerm-javax.mail.search.SearchTerm:A-).

(Do people even read the javadocs anymore?)